# Merge conflict resolution: how to accept all remote changes except the ones in files changed by $AUTHOR?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a private project which was forked from another project in its version 1 (I'll call it ABC). I made several changes to some files and committed these changes into my local repo, but most of the other files were left intact. The tree would more or less look like this:

```
-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o <- abc/master
        \
---------o <- abc/v1
          \
-----------o-o-o-o-o <- mine/master
```

Some time later, ABC releases version 2. The tree, then, changes to this:

```
-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o <- abc/master
        \                       \
---------o <- abc/v1             \
----------\-----------------------o <- abc/v2
           \
------------o-o-o-o-o <- mine/master
```

I want to merge that new version inside my tree, but the new version made many changes to several files I modified myself. I know you can make git prefer the remote modifications rather than the local ones when solving merge conflicts, but the problem is that doing that may erase the changes I've made, which are essential to me.

Is there a way I can tell git to just accept the remote changes when resolving conflicts on files I didn't touch, but leave the files I did touch for me to solve? That is, I want a way to specify that the files changed by some specific author (in this case, me) should not be automatically conflict-resolved.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use [git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash). Running 'git stash' will stash all of your non-committed local changes, and then you can pull in the newer version of ABC. Once you are on the new version of ABC, you can run 'git stash pop' to revive your local changes, and sort the merge conflicts out.

Comment: This is assuming that you haven't made any commits, like you just started working on ABC version 1.

Comment: I have, though. I've edited the description to make my situation clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I don not think there is a direct option to tell git to merge with excluding some files, but you can use `git diff --name-only` to get the file list you have modified. copy file you modified to a backup folder. When doing this, `cp --parents` will help you keeping the file hierarchy.

Next, you run `git merge -s theirs` to get all the modification of other branches to you branch, then overwrite worktree by files in backup folder.

Now `git diff` will show you the difference. you can modify it to do a merge manually.

Comment: This seems the way to go, since many of the problems I'm having come from `git merge` mixing the `v1` and `v2` versions of a file I didn't change. I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: `--theirs` isn't a git merge option

Comment: @Romário Sorry，it should be 'git merge -s theirs'

Comment: There's not a `theirs` git strategy anymore. The closest to that would be `git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs`, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: @Romário, instead of using `git merge`, you can copy all file other branches to overwrite files of your branch and make a commit as what you want, I don't think it is a big problem.